# conexão banco de dados firebird com golang

Tags: firebird, golang

Alguém utiliza Go acessando banco de dados firebird? Estou com problemas de conexão e não estou conseguindo resolver !!

Minha string de conexão

conn, err := sql.Open("firebirdsql", "sysdba:masterkey@localhost:\adhnet\adhmaster.gdb")

Abaixo a mensagem que estou obtendo!

dial tcp: missing address &{0x6604f8 sysdba:masterkey@localhost:\adhnet\adhmaster.gdb 0 {0 0} [] map[] 0 0 0xc042042120 false map[] map[] 0 0 0 }

Comment: Você usa o Windows? Voĉe tentou com a porta? E.g. `...@localhost:3050\\adhnet\\...`.

Comment: dá uma olhada nisso https://github.com/nakagami/firebirdsql